# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration on M1 MAC

Tags: docker, apple-m1, arm64, docker-desktop, testcontainers

I'm trying to run Integration Tests on my local. I'm trying to pull mongo 3.6.0 image, I'm getting following errrors. The same thing is working on non-m1 mac.

*ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.lambda$getFirstValidStrategy$7 -     UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception RuntimeException (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/88/zxy8rm992j10d7_db5w5w2580000gq/T/jna--714400992/jna3748287117789473831.tmp: dlopen(/private/var/folders/88/zxy8rm992j10d7_db5w5w2580000gq/T/jna--714400992/jna3748287117789473831.tmp, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/88/zxy8rm992j10d7_db5w5w2580000gq/T/jna--714400992/jna3748287117789473831.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/jna3748287117789473831.tmp' (no such file)). Root cause UnsatisfiedLinkError
(/private/var/folders/88/zxy8rm992j10d7_db5w5w2580000gq/T/jna--714400992/jna3748287117789473831.tmp: dlopen(/private/var/folders/88/zxy8rm992j10d7_db5w5w2580000gq/T/jna--714400992/jna3748287117789473831.tmp, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/88/zxy8rm992j10d7_db5w5w2580000gq/T/jna--714400992/jna3748287117789473831.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/jna3748287117789473831.tmp' (no such file))*

*Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageName=mongo:3.6.0, imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy())
at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.getDockerImageName(GenericContainer.java:1278)
at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.logger(GenericContainer.java:612)
at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:317)
... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Previous attempts to find a Docker environment failed. Will not retry. Please see logs and check configuration
at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:108)
at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:134)
at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:176)
at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.getDockerClient(LazyDockerClient.java:14)
at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.inspectImageCmd(LazyDockerClient.java:12)
at org.testcontainers.images.LocalImagesCache.refreshCache(LocalImagesCache.java:42)
at org.testcontainers.images.AbstractImagePullPolicy.shouldPull(AbstractImagePullPolicy.java:24)
at org.testcontainers.images.RemoteDockerImage.resolve(RemoteDockerImage.java:66)
at org.testcontainers.images.RemoteDockerImage.resolve(RemoteDockerImage.java:27)
at org.testcontainers.utility.LazyFuture.getResolvedValue(LazyFuture.java:17)
at org.testcontainers.utility.LazyFuture.get(LazyFuture.java:39)
at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.getDockerImageName(GenericContainer.java:1276)*

i've following non root user configuration in my docker file

#Non Root User Configuration
RUN addgroup -S -g 10001 appGrp 
&& adduser -S -D -u 10000 -s /sbin/nologin -h /opt/app/ -G appGrp app
&& chown -R 10000:10001 /opt/app
USER 10000

Comment: Does this example repo run on your M1 machine?
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java-repro

Comment: yes, i can able to run the sample test under this repo

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This worked on my M1 Max Macbook pro, you just have to add an extra dependency with the following version

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you. I already tried it already and its working as expected after adding this.

Comment: I have now successfully moved from the "it doesn't work. Why?" phase onto the "it works. Why?" phase.

Comment: Thank you. It works as expected for me on M2 MacBook Pro by adding this section.
@PaulB the reason is:
Testcontainers uses a library (unixsocket-factory) that relies on Java Native Runtime (JNR), which doesn’t fully support ARM architecture like M1 chips. Adding Java Native Access (JNA) provides a fallback, enabling Testcontainers to work correctly on M1 devices.

Comment: for gradle users:
testImplementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.7.0'

Answer (score 3):

There is apparently a library that older versions of `testcontainers` uses that Apple M1 chips aren't compatible with. This caused `ContainerBasedTestsInitializer` to not find/run a docker container. Upgrading `testcontainers` to  version `1.16.3` worked for me.

```
<testcontainers.version>1.16.3</testcontainers.version>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Docker image `mongo:3.6.0` has no `arm64` [built](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo?tab=tags&page=1&name=3.6.0):

[image]

Can you manually override the Docker image to `mongo:3.6.23`? That should work as this image comes with `arm64` support.

Comment: Yeah, updated momgo version and also change jpa- version in pom.xml. It works now thank you