# Macbook pro M2 Max - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, intellij-idea, apple-m1, testcontainers

I am using Macbook Pro M2 max - IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.1 (Community Edition) - facing docker testcontainers issue

I am trying to execute [this](https://github.com/andreluiz1987/search-store/tree/main) sample elasticsearch project to test new Java API client.

When I run the Maven install command it execute the tests properly. Tests internally uses testcontianers to spin up elasticsearch and perform the tests. But when I run the `SearchCoreServiceTest` separately I get this exception.

Reason

```
01:27:41.035 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception RuntimeException (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.github.dockerjava.transport.DomainSocket). Root cause NoClassDefFoundError (Could not initialize class com.github.dockerjava.transport.DomainSocket)
01:27:41.035 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
01:27:41.036 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy -     UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception RuntimeException (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /Users/mallikarjun/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna7941598394166771476.tmp). Root cause UnsatisfiedLinkError (Can't load library: /Users/mallikarjun/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna7941598394166771476.tmp)
01:27:41.036 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy -     UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception RuntimeException (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.github.dockerjava.transport.DomainSocket). Root cause NoClassDefFoundError (Could not initialize class com.github.dockerjava.transport.DomainSocket)
01:27:41.036 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue
01:27:41.036 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.utility.PrefixingImageNameSubstitutor - No prefix is configured
01:27:41.036 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.utility.ImageNameSubstitutor - Did not find a substitute image for docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.10 (using image substitutor: DefaultImageNameSubstitutor (composite of 'ConfigurationFileImageNameSubstitutor' and 'PrefixingImageNameSubstitutor'))
```

Stacktrace

```
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:550)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConstructorInvocation.proceed(ConstructorInvocation.java:56)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestClassConstructor(InvocationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:302)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:280)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$before$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:196)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerFetchException: Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageName=docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.10, imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy())
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.getDockerImageName(GenericContainer.java:1317)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.logger(GenericContainer.java:641)
    at org.testcontainers.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchContainer.<init>(ElasticsearchContainer.java:73)
    at com.company.searchstore.ElasticsearchInitializer.<clinit>(ElasticsearchInitializer.java:33)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
    at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.lambda$getFirstValidStrategy$7(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:215)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:207)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:135)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:177)
    at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.getDockerClient(LazyDockerClient.java:14)
    at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.listImagesCmd(LazyDockerClient.java:12)
    at org.testcontainers.images.LocalImagesCache.maybeInitCache(LocalImagesCache.java:68)
    at org.testcontainers.images.LocalImagesCache.get(LocalImagesCache.java:32)
    at org.testcontainers.images.AbstractImagePullPolicy.shouldPull(AbstractImagePullPolicy.java:18)
    at org.testcontainers.images.RemoteDockerImage.resolve(RemoteDockerImage.java:67)
    at org.testcontainers.images.RemoteDockerImage.resolve(RemoteDockerImage.java:28)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.LazyFuture.getResolvedValue(LazyFuture.java:17)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.LazyFuture.get(LazyFuture.java:39)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.getDockerImageName(GenericContainer.java:1315)
    ... 67 more
```

I went through this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72716456/java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-find-a-valid-docker-environment-plea) tried to adopt the solutions

`<testcontainers.version>1.16.3</testcontainers.version>`

and

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

But still no use.

Why my test code is not able to start the docker container? any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think you are having latest version of Docker Desktop. So, Go to Settings > Advanced make sure Enable default Docker socket (Requires password) is checked.

Comment: It is already checked. issue still persists

Comment: can you run `ls /var/run/` there should be a docker.sock

Comment: I updated to the latest testcontainers version. it is working. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [thread](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/5266#issuecomment-1099998139) for the solution. Need to use latest version. I used 1.7.6. it works
`<testcontainers.version>1.17.6</testcontainers.version>`